# How to save a django model with multiple images?

Tags: python, django, orm

I've been betting for an hour, but apparently I don't understand something. There is a task to write a scraper with the django admin panel and everything is fine and works here. Now i need to save all the data to the database and here is the problem, only one photo appears in the django admin panel, but everything is downloaded in the media folder.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Apartment(models.Model):
    rooms = models.CharField('кол-во комнат', max_length=64)
    price = models.CharField('цена', max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField('Адрес', max_length=256)
    desc = models.TextField('описание')
    floor = models.CharField('этаж', max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'квартира'
        verbose_name_plural = 'квартиры'


class Image(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'фото'
        verbose_name_plural = 'фото'


class Url(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField('ссылка')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'ссылка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ссылки'
        ordering = ['-created']

#scraper
@receiver(post_save, sender=Url)
def saved_url(instance, created, **kwargs):
    apartments = []

    if created:
        url = instance.url
        soup = make_request(url)
        for link in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-name': 'LinkArea'}):
            url = link.find('a').get('href')
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                rooms = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1][@data-name="OfferTitle"]/h1').text
            except:
                rooms = None
            try:
                price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1]/div/span/span[1][@itemprop="price"]').text
            except:
                price = None
            try:
                address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                              '//section/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[@itemprop="name"]').get_attribute(
                    'content')
            except:
                address = None
            try:
                desc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div/span/p[@itemprop="description"]').text
            except:
                desc = None
            try:
                floor = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div/div[4]/div[1][@data-testid="object-summary-description-value"]').text
            except:
                floor = None
            try:
                photos = [img.get_attribute('src') for img in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'fotorama__img')]
            except:
                photos = None
            
            apartments.append(
                {
                    'rooms': rooms,
                    'price': price,
                    'address': address,
                    'desc': desc,
                    'floor': floor,
                    'photos': photos,
                }
            )

            save_data(apartments)

#save function 
def save_data(apartments_list):

    for ap in apartments_list:
        im = Image()
        try:
            apartment = Apartment.objects.create(
                rooms=ap['rooms'],
                price=ap['price'],
                address=ap['address'],
                desc=ap['desc'],
                floor=ap['floor'],
            )
            for image in ap['photos']:
                pic = urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, image.split('/')[-1])[0]
                im.img = im.img.save(pic, File(open(pic, 'rb')))
                im.apartment = apartment
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data in `apartments_list` ?

Comment: You need to create a new `Image` for each image that you want to save. You are currently reusing and updating the same `Image` object again and again

Comment: have now added the scraper function

Comment: @IainShelvington Ok, but how do I do that, because ap ['photos'] is a url list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not actually saving the image .
try to change this

```
def save_data(apartments_list):

    for ap in apartments_list:
        im = Image()
        try:
            apartment = Apartment.objects.create(
                rooms=ap['rooms'],
                price=ap['price'],
                address=ap['address'],
                desc=ap['desc'],
                floor=ap['floor'],
            )
            for image in ap['photos']:
                pic = urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, image.split('/')[-1])[0]
                im.img = im.img.save(pic, File(open(pic, 'rb')))
                im.apartment = apartment
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

to

```
def save_data(apartments_list):

    for ap in apartments_list:
        
        try:
            apartment = Apartment.objects.create(
                rooms=ap['rooms'],
                price=ap['price'],
                address=ap['address'],
                desc=ap['desc'],
                floor=ap['floor'],
            )
            for image in ap['photos']:
                im = Image()
                pic = urllib.request.urlretrieve(image)[0]            
                im.img.save(image, File(open(pic, 'rb')))
                im.apartment = apartment
                im.save() #new
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

Comment: thanks, but I've already tried that, then I get an image object in the admin panel

Comment: @Evgeny which image object did you get ? could you show me what you got ? if you get Image Object[..] That means that you did not specify  `def __str__(self)`  in your model.

Comment: For example Image object (189) and there is no image and only one available. But there are 15 pictures

Comment: @Evgeny when you click on that object in the detail page what do you see.

Comment: i can't click on it

Comment: @Evgeny why you can't ?

Comment: I can't click on it, it's above the search field

Comment: @Evgeny is it working now ?

Comment: Yes! It’s working now!